# Unable to create subsite with SharePoint hosted app

Tags: jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app, sub-site, app

Below is my code for creating sub site in SharePoint Hosted App:

```
function createWebsite() 
{
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("https://rootSite/sites/Site1");
     this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
     var webCreationInfo = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
     webCreationInfo.set_title(projectName);
     webCreationInfo.set_language(1033);
     webCreationInfo.set_url('RM4');
     webCreationInfo.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(true);
     webCreationInfo.set_webTemplate('STS#0');

     oWebsite.get_webs().add(webCreationInfo);
     oWebsite.update();

     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}
```

But the site isn't created. I am getting error

[image]

Is it like anything that we can't use `ClientContext` in SP hosted app?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the proper app permissions in `AppManifest.xml` ?

Comment: This is not a way to create client context in SP hosted add ins. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/841321/How-to-initialize-the-SharePoint-Client-Context-in

Comment: @Ronak - Yes. Given Full control to Tenant and site Collection

Comment: @Amit - Can you please tell me the way how to create it

Comment: In code project link i have shared they have mentioned it. Please check if it helps.

Comment: Also Note that: The app has permissions to execute code in full control only if the user executing the code has full control of the Site collection.
So you must make sure that the users has permissions to create a subsite as well. You can not elevate permissions in a SharePoint hosted app.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot this looks like non-sharepoint issue.. The code at the screenshot is not the same as the function that you pasted, so we cannot be sure in which scope it's running..

You should try to rewrite that line to:

```
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
```

Comment: This is most definately the correct error, using `this` is what kills the code